# Informix - DEFINE syntax error while creating procedure

Tags: sql, database, syntax-error, informix, dbeaver

When creating a procedure in Informix 12.10 I got a "Syntax error", so I reduced the procedure to the minimum, and it seems that Informix doesn't like "DEFINE":

```
CREATE PROCEDURE migrate_table()
    DEFINE f_number INTEGER;
END PROCEDURE;
```

This throws

> Error occurred during SQL script execution  Razón: SQL Error [42000]:
> A syntax error has occurred.

But if I execute:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE migrate_table()
END PROCEDURE;
```

I get no errors...

Comment: I'd try DECLARE instead of DEFINE.

Comment: Which program are you using to execute this statement?  Are you, perchance, using `isql` rather than `dbaccess`?  When I use DB-Access, the procedure works.  If I used `isql`, the procedure would be incorrectly parsed, I believe, and the `END PROCEDURE;` would not be sent with the rest of the statement, which makes it into a syntax error.

Comment: @jarlh I tried with DECLARE and I get the same error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm using DBeaver. I'll try dbaccess

Comment: The presence of semicolons in the middle of a CREATE PROCEDURE statement complicates the parsing — normally, you only need to find the first semicolon that is not in a string of comment to find the end of the statement.  CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION statements break this simplistic parsing.  So, you have to analyze what you find and if it is CREATE [DBA] [FUNCTION|PROECDURE], you have to continue until you find the semicolon after END PROCEDURE (there can be documentation information after that).  That's where `isql` fails; it's presumably where some other tools fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
delimiter /
CREATE PROCEDURE migrate_table()
    DEFINE f_number INTEGER;
END PROCEDURE;
/
```

select all, and execute.. (in dbeaver)